# What is morphological analysis, as it applies to bible study?

Tags: bible-translation, language, hebrew, greek

As far as I can tell, it's a technique used by bible students to better understand the original languages in context.

How does one go about using a tool such as Robinson's Morphological Analysis Codes?

Edit: I've also asked [*this same question*](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2243/691) on Hermeneutics.SE.

Comment: Not sure, but this might be a question for http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is an excellent beginner hermeneutics question. @JonEricson. Do want this or do you want us to answer it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was [*answered*](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2243/691) on Biblical Hermeneutics.SE.

Morphological analysis codes are used in the study of the original languages of the Bible. For example, a word might be listed with the morphological code "A-NPM," which would indicate the following:

**A-NPM**

- Part of Speech: Adjective
- Case: Nominative (subject; predicate nominative)
- Number: Plural
- Gender: Masculine

Follow the link provided above for more information.